# grails production jdbc pooling commons-dbcp vs tomcat 7 jndi

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails, jndi, apache-commons-dbcp

What is a recommended production configuration for tomcat grails jdbc access?

commons-dbcp or tomcat jndi polling?

Does anyone have performance or anecdotal advice in regards to this configuration?

We have been fighting configuration and possibly transaction issues using Grails and tomcat jndi, and we are trying to decide if we want to invest more time in debugging those issues, or just use commons-dbcp.

This may be considered a duplicate of [tomcat-dbcp vs commons-dbcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711943/tomcat-dbcp-vs-commons-dbcp), but I am looking for performance data and advice in regards to Grails.

If it matters, we are using MySQL :)

Comment: What are the actual transaction errors you are getting in Grails?  Are you having real performance problems? Because tomcat-dbcp is based on apache-commons-dbcp, you could see the same problem and you might be better served by switching to something like C3P0 or going with a different application server. [SpringSource tc-Server's DBCP](http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric52/topic/com.vmware.vfabric.tc-server.2.8/admin/manual-high-concurrency-jdbc.html) "adds additional features to support highly-concurrent environments and multiple core/cpu systems"

Comment: Drew the hibernate issues where not driver related.  Do you have any numbers on tc server dbcp?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you watch: Debugging Grails Database Performance

http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/groovy-grails/debugging-grails-database-performance