# ClassNotFoundException: BasicDataSourceFactory

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have a JAVA application that runs fine in my local Windows7 environment on Tomcat7. I am trying to put this into production in a Linux environment. 
Everything is done and is working fine except when my application tries to access the DB. Operations where DB is not involved, it works fine.
The error I get is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory
```

This class is part of tomcat-dbcp.jar. This is placed in my $CATALINA_HOME/lib folder. Why is this still not getting picked up? Please help!

UPDATE: I also opened up the .jar file and checked. The org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.class file is present.

Comment: Are you sure that `CATALINA_HOME` is correct?

Comment: Pretty much... when I echo $CATALINA_HOME I get the path of the tomcat directory where I installed it /installables/apache-tomcat-7.0.35
Can I check it using another way?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a duplicate somewhere in your classpath?

Comment: Does the container have read permission to the tomcat-dbcp.jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was finally able to crack it. My mistake - I was relying only on echo $CATALINA_HOME to check its location. Turns out that this can be misleading. 
It is better to use

```
ps aux | grep catalina
```

In the output that comes look for catalina.base and catalina.home. The path given in front of these variables is the path from where Tomcat libs are being fetched. I had done a default installation and found the libs under /usr/share/tomcat7. As it turns out, the default installation done using yum did not provide the tomcat-dbcp.jar file. Instead it provided the commons-dbcp.jar. Read about [tomcat-dbcp vs commons-dbcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711943/tomcat-dbcp-vs-commons-dbcp)

Changing the lib files under the usr/share/tomcat7 folder required me to use sudo bash. Also you may notice that the lib folder under /usr/share/tomcat7 is a simlink. Just do ls /usr/share/tomcat7 -l to get the parent location. You will be able to make changes only in the parent location.
Similar things can be checked for server.xml which is also finally being picked from /usr/share/tomcat7 itself.

The best way to manage all these is to create your own simlinks so that you don't need to bother about going to various locations after the first time.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.