# Why does the RedHat/Centos tomcat rpm include commons-dbcp and commons-pool?

Tags: tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp

Why does the RedHat/Centos `tomcat7` (and `tomcat8`) rpm include `apache-commons-dbcp` and `apache-commons-pool` libs as dependencies and symlink them into `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`?

My understanding is that tomcat provides a repackaged (and renamed) version of both these libs as `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib/tomcat-dbcp`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319393/48413) for a description of this.

It seems redundant to include the original copy of the commons libs themselves - but I'm assuming there's a reason for it. Does anybody know?